# Dial a number by tapping a TextView Android

Tags: java, android

I have a page in my app that deals with contact information. I want to be able to tap a TextView that contains the number to call. Similar to tapping a link in a TextView and it opens in a web browser.

Can I add some html like tags to the string to get it to call?

```
<TextView android:text="@string/contact_phone_number"
    style="@style/AppSubTextStyle" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use android:autoLink="phone"
and will auto make a call to the number